# Mobile-Ready Site, How to alert?

Tags: user-interface, mobile

What's the Best way to let people know that a site can also be viewed in mobile devices?

Am thinking about putting something in the footer for computer users, that is hidden for mobile devices with `display: none;`, but what to put in there is the question?  I've been searching google, and don't really see any images that say Mobile-Ready or something that would be unobtrusive to computer users that could let them know that the site is also optimized for mobile devices as well.

For example, what do other sites do about this?  Should I even bother with worrying about this?

Also, we are using a mobile script in Javascript from this site here:  http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ that returns a boolean value false, if it is not any mobile devices that it searches for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing, not programming.

Comment: You also have to decide on what is a "mobile device". Phones are alright but what about tablets? And when you have decided on that - what about phablets? Then think of Win8 on a tablet like the Surface Pro; it is a hydra with both a desktop and a tablet (metro/modern) GUI where IE10 runs in both.  We have been through this in a recent project of mine and had reasons to react to both OS and size. FWIW

Comment: I see.  Well, we've tested on tablets, i-pads, and mobile phones (Androids, IPhones, etc.).  That's really all.  Haven't tested on any other devices though...

Comment: @Quentin - I believe it is about both marketing and programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about User Experience, not SO

Comment: This is about User Experience IMO and isn't programming related. A link in the footer to force switch between *Mobile version* and *Desktop* is a good practice. Let the user decide or if you make a choice for him, let him change his (your) mind. One of the reason is a false detection of a mobile: Android has a lot of resolutions from 320 to (very) High Density and there is a countless number of smartphones (bada, BB, Nokia, soon Fx OS, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting people know you have a mobile website isn't needed. Also a mobile-device website a part from the normal website isn't really '2013'.

I should go for

> CSS @media-queries.

So in this case the people who visit it on desktop have no clue it's responsive, and people that visit the mobile-site don't know it's the same website, because of the @media-queries.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using already... `media queries`.  It's all in CSS and one site.  I don't really support making a totally different site for mobile devices... so it's all on 1 site and is mobile-ready and fine in mobile devices as well as computers.

Comment: So there's no need to 'alert' people for mobile-website support. Nowadays almost all new websites are responsive using @media-queries, so I should leave it as it is now :)

Comment: We have a dedicated group of people that have been with the site for over 20 years, and some are not keen to mobile web sites, and some are.  But, just recently, we've built a Micro Site that will attract a lot of traffic and would like to alert people that this site can also be viewed in mobile devices, mainly since this is the first time that we have catered to mobile devices and it may not be apparent to our dedicated users.

Comment: Then I would suggest a dicreet banner.

Comment: That changes it a bit. You could indeed use some kind of dicreet banner in your  case.

Comment: Yes, I have been considering this for quite some time now, but I can't find anything that would be appropriate, universally understood, branded properly, etc. that is a generic term/image for this.  Like there isn't any that I can find.  For example, there are images that say 100% HTML 5 Compliant, or HTML 5 Validated, but nothing for mobile devices.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will talk to our graphics designer about this tomorrow and see what he thinks.  We'll have to create one from scratch.  Fine by me, just thought there would be a properly identifiable image somewhere for this already.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: For the sake of putting up with this question and following up with it, even though we will be most likely using a discreet banner in the footer of the Micro Site, and the fact that I don't like to leave questions unanswered, I've given you this answer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother, people will see (and hopefully not notice) that it works when then visit your site on a mobile device.

Comment: Ok, but this is something new for the company that I work for, so mobile devices weren't really supported in the past, but that was before I came onto the scene... so it's probably expected by many to not work in mobile devices...

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tagged the Q as CSS but if you have control over the backend you could first decided on what is a "mobile device" and then send back different data.

Comment: Well, we are using the Javascript file located here:  http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ for detecting mobile devices.  So that returns a boolean false if they are not on any of these mobile devices.

Comment: ofcourse we are also using css media queries, but css can't do everything either.  Some jQuery scripting is needed for mobile devices, which is why we are using the `detectmobilebrowsers.js` file from that site.

Comment: A mobile device is defined in that script:  `detectmobilebrowser.js`